# Django. Accessing Model.objects

Tags: django, parent-child

```
class SeoBasic(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', blank=True, null=True)
   ...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    duplicate = SeoBasic.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exclude(pk=self.pk).count() > 0
    if duplicate:
      #update slug to be unique

    super(SeoBasic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class ModelA(SeoBasic):
   pass

class ModelB(SeoBasic):
   pass
```

Is it possible to update save method of SeoBasic, so that ModelA and ModelB will search for duplicates only in they own class?

Sure i can add save() method into ModelA and ModelB. But is there any way to write code in the parent class without modifying code in child classes?

Edit:
in ModelA i need slug field to be unique for modelA and in modelB it must be unique for modelB, but it's also possible that ModelA.slug = ModelB.slug

Comment: What is it that your trying to achieve exactly? It's hard to follow.

Comment: Just use `django-autoslug`, Jesus.

Comment: in ModelA i need slug field to be unique for modelA and in modelB it must be unique for modelB, but it's also possible that ModelA.slug = ModelB.slug.